Encrypting process makes flutter app frozen until its done
[Solved]  I am making a flutter app and inside it the user can watch or download videos
After downloading a video I want to encrypt it and then store it because I don't want the user to be able to share it.
The encrypting process is being performed correctly however when it starts the app freezes for like 10 seconds before its finished and the app unfreezes
I tried multiple encrypting methods but had the same result
I read somewhere here that using "compute" methode and changing the function type to "FutureOr" can solve the problem. However, I cant seem to use it correctly.
Any help would be appreciated.
  Future<void> downloadVideo(String url) async {
    var appDocDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir!.path;
    String filePath = '$appDocPath/Videos/${url.split('/').last}';

    try {
      var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      var response = await request.close();
      List<int> bytes = [];
      int downloaded = 0;
      int total = response.contentLength!;
      response.listen(
        (List<int> newBytes) {
          bytes.addAll(newBytes);
          downloaded += newBytes.length;
          downloadProgress.value = downloaded / total;
          print("Download progress: ${downloadProgress.value}");
        },
        onDone: () async {
          // Generate encryption key and IV
          final key = encrypt.Key.fromSecureRandom(32);
          final iv = encrypt.IV.fromSecureRandom(16);

          // Encrypt the video bytes
          final encrypter =
              encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc));
          final encryptedBytes = encrypter.encryptBytes(bytes, iv: iv).bytes;

          // Store the key and IV securely
          final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
          await storage.write(key: 'key_$filePath', value: key.base64);
          await storage.write(key: 'iv_$filePath', value: iv.base64);

          // Save the encrypted video
          File file = File(filePath);
          await file.writeAsBytes(encryptedBytes);
          print("Download completed: $filePath");
        },
        onError: (e) {
          print("Error downloading video: $e");
        },
        cancelOnError: true,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error downloading video: $e");
    }
  }

Update :
The problem was solved using isolate function. I tried it multiple times before posting here but always ending up with an exception
Illegal argument in isolate message: object is unsendable

But was able to solve that by ,of course, separating the encryption logic from the download into another function, and then making the encryption function static.

Since Dart is single threaded, if you perform a compute-bound operation in one go, you should expect everything to stall. Using async methods or Future will not help. Using compute or another way to start another isolate will help - but you don't show why it isn't working for you. Note that encryptBytes is just a wrapper around pointycastle which implements the AES round in software. Other packages (e.g. the ones based around sodium) use the hardware AES round instructions. You'll likely find that their GCM mode implementations are faster than the CBC impl you are using.

By default, Dart performs all tasks in a single thread. So, when a large computation process is initiated you may experience lag in the UI.
You can use Isolates in this case to move the heavy load to be processed by an entirely different thread. You can simply use the Isolate.run method to do so. Instead of calling your downloadVideo method directly, call it as the following code in your main thread:
  final url = "..."; // Your download URL

  Isolate.run(() async {
    await downloadVideo(url);
  });

Here's more info on Isolates on YouTube | Flutter and on Dart documentation.
Hope this helps :)

I tried doing that , I always end up with an exception :
Exception has occurred. ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: object is unsendable - Library:'dart:isolate' Class: _ReceivePortImpl@1026248 (see restrictions listed at SendPort.send() documentation for more information)
I read somewhere that dart latest sdk applied strict rules to the kind of data you can send.
This is where am using it :
await Isolate.run(() async {             _encryptAndSave;             EncryptParams(bytes, filePath, receivePort.sendPort);           }); 

Never mind.
Just solved the problem by separating the encryption logic into another function and then make it static.
The exceptions was misleading.
I'll update my post.
